# Get all simple products that have global product attribute brand in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

In woocommerce I's trying to retrieve all products that have global attribute *brand*. from my prior understandings and also some googling  I have done this so far:

```
function handle_custom_query_var($query, $query_vars)
{
    if (!empty($query_vars['with_brand'])) {
        $query['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'pa_brand',
        'field'    => 'term_id', 
        'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_store_cpt_get_products_query', 'handle_custom_query_var', 10, 2);

$args = array(
    'status' => 'publish',
    'type' => 'simple',
    'limit' => 50,
    'paginate' => true,
    'page' => $request['page'],
    'with_brand' => true
);  
$results = wc_get_products($args);
```

but still I'm getting simple products with no brand attribute. what I'm doing wrong?
// PS: kindly ignore unrelated paramethers inside wc_get_products arguments

I also tried
`'operator' => 'IN'`

instead of
`'compare' => 'EXISTS'`

But it did not work as well.

Comment: its not meta_query its tax_query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `tax_query` and 'compare' has to be replaced with 'operator' like:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_store_cpt_get_products_query', 'handle_pa_brand_product_attribute', 10, 2);
function handle_pa_brand_product_attribute($query, $query_vars)
{
    if ( isset($query_vars['brand']) && $query_vars['brand'] === 'EXISTS' ) {
        $query['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'pa_brand',
            'operator'  => esc_attr($query_vars['brand']),
        );
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Then your WC_Product_Query will be:

```php
    $args = array(
        'status'    => 'publish',
        'type'      => 'simple',
        'limit'     => 50,
        'paginate'  => true,
        'page'      => $request['page'],
        'brand'     => 'EXISTS',
    );  
    $results = wc_get_products($args);
```

Tested and works.

---

###### Addition: Handling multiple product attributes.

You can handle multiple product attributes (here we use "Brand" and "Color"):

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_store_cpt_get_products_query', 'handle_specific_product_attributes', 10, 2);
function handle_specific_product_attributes($query, $query_vars)
{
    // "Brand" with "EXISTS" parametter
    if ( isset($query_vars['brand']) && $query_vars['brand'] === 'EXISTS' ) {
        $query['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'pa_brand',
            'operator'  => esc_attr($query_vars['brand']),
        );
    }

    // "Color" with term "slug" parametter
    if ( isset($query_vars['color']) && ! empty($query_vars['color']) ) {
        $terms = (array) implode(',', esc_attr($query_vars['color']));

        $query['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'pa_color',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => $terms,
        );
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Then an example of WC_Product_Query using both:

```php
    $args = array(
        'status'    => 'publish',
        'type'      => 'simple',
        'limit'     => 50,
        'paginate'  => true,
        'page'      => $request['page'],
        'brand'     => 'EXISTS',
        'color'     => 'red,green',
    );  
    $results = wc_get_products($args);
```

Comment: You've done beautifully. How to generalize it? for eaxample if I want to have products that have attribute brand and color or whatever else?

Comment: @EDSA I have added an addition example…